# Using a ternary operator to render conditionally by mapping through an array

Tags: reactjs, mapping, jsx, conditional-operator, conditional-rendering

I am attempting to conditionally render items of an array from [json placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users), by using a ternary operator to establish if an array has any items, then map through it, and return the items. If not, return a message indicating so. I've searched to see if/where my syntax is wrong to no avail.

Here's what I have:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchUsers } from "../../lib/functions";

const Users = () => {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchUsers().then(res => setUsers(res.data))
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="users">
            <h1>Users</h1>
            {users.length ? users.map((user) => {
                (<div key="id">
                    <h4>{users.name}</h4>
                    <h5>{users.email}</h5>
                    <h6>{users.username}</h6>
                    <p>{users.address}</p>
                </div>) :
                (
                    <div>
                        <p>User not found.</p>
                    </div>
                )})}
        </div>
    );
}


export default Users;
```

It's throwing me this error:

ERROR in [eslint]
src/components/users/Users.js
Line 19:23:  Parsing error: Missing semicolon. (19:23)

webpack compiled with 2 errors

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: Missing the `return` inside your `map` callback function.

Comment: @Mbistami, I've edited to show the error.

Comment: the error is coming from linter you need to add a semicolon please read the issue semicolon needs to be placed in row 19 column 23 as your error says to which line and which column when you have `value1:value2` value1 is the row and 2 is the column..

Comment: Thanks @Nick...I can't seem to get that right even when I had it in

Comment: @Mbistami, thank you for that pointer. Even so, where the linter is asking me to add a semicolon, I have a colon there to separate the two expressions of the ternary operator. Does that clarify?

Comment: Then you need a return and a screenshot of the issue I wrote the update for the return issue and about the linter I just need a clear screenshot to understand why is the linter claiming semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your use of the `ternary operator` is wrong.
Only first `div` should be in the `map` but according to your code, both of `div` are in the `map`.

```
{users.length ? users.map((user) => 
  (<div key="id">
    <h4>{users.name}</h4>
    <h5>{users.email}</h5>
    <h6>{users.username}</h6>
    <p>{users.address}</p>
  </div>))
  :
  (<div>
    <p>User not found.</p>
  </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing return map function doesn't automatically return a value you need to specify what to return as follows:

```js
{users.length ? users.map((user) => {
                return (<div key="id">
                    <h4>{users.name}</h4>
                    <h5>{users.email}</h5>
                    <h6>{users.username}</h6>
                    <p>{users.address}</p>
                </div>) :
                (
                    <div>
                        <p>User not found.</p>
                    </div>
                )})}
```